# Selecting a series of grouped layers within a specific extent

Tags: arcpy, clip, group-layer

Is there a way to select grouped layers within a specific extent with ArcGIS 10.5?

For example I have a constraint mapping, with various thematic layers grouped by interest. I would like to know which one are applicable in my project area, without having to select and clip each layer individually (too many of them). Ideally a tool that would let me grab the group of layer and create a shp or layer of features present within my work area would be great.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  For anything like this I would use ArcPy.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the layers are all in the current MXD, you could try something like this using Python and arcpy:

```
extentOfInterest = arcpy.Extent(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if extentOfInterest.overlaps(layer.getExtent()):
        print "Layer overlaps and will be processed:  " + layer.longName
        #  Clip, etc here
```

Replacing `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax` with the minimum and maximum values for your extent of interest.  You could even turn it into a script tool, and pass these values in as parameters.

Alternatively, you could create the extentOfInterest as the envelope of a polygon feature.

Optionally, you can filter the layers by the layers' names (as a wildcard string in the `ListLayers()`), or by which group they are in (using the `layer.longName`, which includes group hierarchy), to process only the layers that you're interested in.

**UPDATE**:  As suggested in comments below, you may also want to filter the layers based on `layer.isFeatureLayer` and/or `layer.isGroupLayer`.  It depends on what your needs actually are.

Comment: From the sound of the question you might need a nested for layer loop, if layer.isGroupLayer: for gLayer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(layer): as the OP is looking at group layers that intersect, presumably at least one layer. You should also test if gLayer.isFeatureLayer before using overlap.. but just because a layers' extent overlaps doesn't mean there's features in the area of interest, at some point you'd need to do a select layer by location and return a selection count.

Comment: Good points.  I think I might leave it simple for now though, as the question is a little vague.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was hoping for a way to proceed without a python script as my scripting knowledge is fairly basic but will give it a go.